# Is there an online algorithm for solving any P-complete problem?

Tags: reference-request, complexity-classes, online-algorithms

We can think of the class $NC$ as the class of problems that can be solved in parallel, whereas a $P$-complete problem probably has no parallel solution.  My question is: where do online algorithms fit in this spectrum?

My intuition says that online problems are more difficult than parallel problems.  This would be more-or-less confirmed by the existence of an online algorithm for a $P$-complete problem.  So do any exist?

Alternatively, we could define a complexity class for online problems $O$ such that:
$$
NC \subseteq O \subseteq P
$$
Then we would have to define $O$-complete problems and convince ourselves that they cannot be parallelized.

Any advice on what I should read to think about this some more?

Comment: What causes you to suggest that there is an online algorithm for every problem in NC?

Comment: Monoid computations that take constant time are complete in $NC^1$ and they can be done online.  In my experience, other problems that I've found in $NC$ also have reasonable online algorithms by a similar argument.  Basically, each new data point is a new, independent branch in the algorithm.  I'm certainly open to the possibility of there being an $NC$ algorithm that can't be made online, my intuition just says "probably not."

Comment: I'm wondering what a reasonable computation model for such a class would look like. 
A DTM with a work tape of $log(n)$ length where each chunk of the input is written successively after some state "next_chunk" is entered. The work tape should probably not require more than $O(log(n))$ space. Now for time measurement we could analyze the worst-cast of how many steps it takes to before the "next_chunk" state is entered again(e.g. denoted by $T(n)$) now $\frac{n}{log(n)} T(n)$ can be used to relate it to the generic TIME class

Comment: What does it mean for a decision problem to have an online algorithm?

Comment: The [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of an [explicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Explicit_extractors) s[trong extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Strong_extractors) can be computed in $P$, but if $\:k,\epsilon,d,m\:$ are all small then it can't be computed by an online algorithm. $\;\;\;$

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019012002980 -- _Online integer packing with recourse_. If I recall, they give constant-competitive algorithms for some integer linear programs. The algorithms are online with recourse (they can change a limited number of their decisions retroactively), while the offline problem is NP-hard and has no poly-time constant approximation algorithms unless P=NP.

Comment: similar question here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40669/is-there-any-online-problem-that-the-best-known-competitive-ratio-is-better-than .  p.s. Hi Mike!